# Is it possible to make KDE 4 look like Win98?

Tags: kde

I found settings which make windows look like in Win98, but cannot change taskbar colors and sizes. Default colors are breaking my eyes. Please, write instructions how to change taskbar and other components which significantly lower usability. Version of KDE is 4.8 and newer.

EDIT: After applying Aya theme as xenoterracide suggested, taskbar looks as this:
[image: Aya taskbar].
Is it a bug or colors indeed so crazy?

Comment: You might have better luck with another desktop environment, like XFCE.

Comment: that text looks off, you'll note in my screenshots the text is a little darker... and the background a little lighter, I wonder if fedora modified it.

Comment: updated my answer with a suggestion for different themes

Answer (score 2):

(using 4.9.1 ) Overall desktop theme settings are still scattered, I hope that this is fixed in a couple of upcoming releases.

To change the desktop them (which controls the taskbar) go to `System Settings` ->  `Workspace Appearance` -> `Desktop Theme`. You probably want Aya, though you can download others (you may need to), there's also a details tab which allows you to customize more specifics.[image: desktop theme settings]

To change the taskbar size click its `cashew` and unlock widgets if they are not. you should see a height adjustment option, resize as desired.[image]

To get even closer to windows you'll want to change your cursor theme to KDE Classic, and your Window Decorations to Redmond. Aya is not the best theme for looking like windows, I checked out the `Get New Themes` and found one called "win-classic" it appears to look ok for the most part, I think a texture is missing for the selected window in the task bar. That theme may need updating before it is usable. You may find other themes that are a good fit.

Answer (score 0):

You may try `Redmond97` theme from [GitHub](https://github.com/matthewmx86/Redmond97) or [Pling](https://www.pling.com/p/1313764) for window decoration (but I don't know if it works with KDE) and [SE98](https://www.pling.com/p/1581320/) for icons in 98's style (works well with KDE and TDE).